# ATTiny Default AREF

Tags: arduino, attiny, voltage-reference

I am trying to get the Adafruit Electret Microphone Amplifier to work with an ATTiny85 but am having some trouble with the reference voltage.
I am using a 5V circuit because I am also powering a strip of LEDs and I am trying to avoid making the circuit too complicated with a bunch of extra regulators.
Since the chip should use the supply voltage as reference by default I figured I would be fine in using 5V across the board. But I get basically no response out of the mic when doing this. However, if I hook up 5V to AREF and then call analogReference(EXTERNAL), everything works fine.

Any thoughts as to why this would be the case? This completely goes against my understanding (and experience) of the default AREF on the ATMega chips.

It would be nice to be able to use that AREF pin for something else :)

Side Note: I am going to be powering this with batteries so maybe I just need it anyways? But again, I thought the default mode was to use VCC as the reference...

Comment: You mention three different platforms: ATtiny85, ATmega and Arduino. They are closely related, but which one are you using? Please include a link to the appropriate datasheet and the appropriate parts of the code.

Comment: If you suspect you're assumption about default reference voltage is wrong, why not explicitly force it in your code, it only takes couple of bytes.

Comment: I am using an ATTiny85 but on the Arduino code platform. I know it only takes up a couple of bytes in code but it takes up a whole I/O pin that I would rather be able to use...

Comment: You can force it to the (assumed) default Vcc in a few bytes and without sacrificing the pin.

Comment: Ok... could you tell me how to do that? All I know is to call analogReference() and none of it's options seem to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: analogReference(DEFAULT) ? The reference is shut down by default. It is enabled when the ADC is enabled and it has a start up time. Also check if AREF is set for an internal voltage reference *with external capacitor*. Check the datasheet for the ADMUX register, you can easily write to the register with `ADMUX=n;`. Check this little program of mine that uses Vcc as reference on an ATtiny13: http://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=adc2pwm13;a=blob;f=dimmer.cpp;h=6a582a45b1b49216f349083abf0cb07dc0e874e4;hb=813acb83cb1149cce7d613f3b6b4ebfc3184ddb0

Comment: I assumed that DEFAULT was what it was set to if you did nothing, so it did not need to be set manually??

Comment: Only one way to find out if that is true for programming tiny's through Arduino. I have no experience with that method, but I do know that not all libraries and mechanisms will work with all controllers. Consider dropping into chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are changing the A/D reference mode somewhere else in your code? You can double check this by adding a call to `analogReference(DEFAULT)` just before your call to `analogRead()`. This should select Vcc as the input to the A/D Mux on the ATTINY85 just as you expected.

Here is the ADMUX register from the ATTINY85 datasheet...
[image: ATTINY85 ADMUX Register]

Here is the relevant code excerpted from the Arduino library....

```
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny24__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny44__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny25__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny45__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__)
65  #define DEFAULT 0
66  #define EXTERNAL 1
67  #define INTERNAL 2

uint8_t analog_reference = DEFAULT;

void analogReference(uint8_t mode)
{
        // can't actually set the register here because the default setting
        // will connect AVCC and the AREF pin, which would cause a short if
        // there's something connected to AREF.
        analog_reference = mode;
}

int analogRead(uint8_t pin)
{
        uint8_t low, high;

        if (pin >= 14) pin -= 14; // allow for channel or pin numbers

        // set the analog reference (high two bits of ADMUX) and select the
        // channel (low 4 bits).  this also sets ADLAR (left-adjust result)
        // to 0 (the default).
        ADMUX = (analog_reference << 6) | (pin & 0x07); 
...
```